# Definitions of Dedekind cuts in Geometry

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, proof-verification

When defining $\mathbb{R}$ from the rationals they use Dedekind cuts and there are basically two definitions:

**Version 1**:

> A Dedekind cut is any set $A\subseteq \mathbb{Q}$ with the following
>   three properties:
>
> (I) $A$ is not empty, and $A\neq \mathbb{Q}$.
>
> (II) If $p\in A, q\in \mathbb{Q}$, and $q< p$, then $q\in A$.
>
> (III) If $p\in A$, then $p<r$ for some $r\in A$

**Version 2**:

> A Dedekind cut is an ordered pair of subsets of $\mathbb{Q}$,
>   $(A,B)$, satisfying:
>
> (I) $\{A,B\}$ is a partition of $\mathbb{Q}$
>
> (II) $p<q$ for all $p\in A$, $q\in B$
>
> (III) $A$ does not have a greatest element

The main difference between them is that the first one names the set $A$ as a cut while in the second a cut is the pair $(A,B)$.

Now, in Geometry (From Greenberg's book) there is what I think is the analogous definition for the second version:

> **Dedekind cut in Geometry**: A Dedekind cut of a line $l$ is a partition of $l$ into two non-empty subsets $A$ and $B$ such that no
>   point of either subset is between two points of the other.

**Question**: I haven't seen any place that uses the first version of the Dedekind cuts for Geometry, and I wonder why. Is there a reason? What is the analogous (standard?) definition of Dedekid cut in Geometry for the first version?.

Thanks

Comment: The second definition doesn't really work, because according to it there are two _different_ cuts that intuitively represent each rational, depending on whether you put that rational in $A$ or in $B$.

Comment: Well, you can use betweenness to induce a total order on the line, and just carbon copy the definition. Also, to correct the mistake @HenningMakholm hints to, people usually assume $A$ to be open (that is, it has no _maximal_ element.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks. I just did the correction. I think your idea of inducing a total order works. It would be nice though if it could be done just like in Greenberg's definition, without appealing to extra definitions.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: But now your geometric definition is not analogous to your Version 2, because the mistake was not fixed there. (And without having a preferred direction on the line in question, it seems to be hard do fix elegantly). (Also, where did the requirement that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty go?)

Comment: @HenningMakholm The geometric definition is just analogous in the sense of having a partition into sets $A$ and $B$. What I'd like to have is the analogous of the first version, meaning getting a geometric definition in terms of just a set $A$ with some given conditions. The requirements that $A$ and $B$ are none-empty are included in (I) because of the definition of partition.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: Would something like "unbounded, not being the entire line, and containing every point between two points in it" for you?

Comment: @HenningMakholm To use the term unbounded I'd need an order, which I'd I like to avoid. Anyway, my question is more in the sense of the existence of a "standard" definition already given or used in a textbook, etc.

Comment: @DanielaDiaz: Geometically, "unbounded" can be phrased as "not contained inside any circle".